# Get the name of instance as string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Im working with `Three.js` and `javascript`.
When my code executes this:

```
console.log(this.scene.children[1])
```

I get this in my console of Chrome:
[image]

How can I get the name of the object ('WidgetsRuler') as a string?
I dont see any attribute that saves this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I Solved it using:

```
console.log(this.scene.children[1].constructor.name)
```

Comment: It says I have to wait 2 days

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to use `prototype` to achieve this:

```
Object.prototype.toString
```

eg:

```
Console.Log(this.scene.children[1].prototype.toString())
```

Failing that, you can try `constructor`:

```
console.log(this.scene.children[1].constructor.name)
```

Comment: Thanks sk93! The console says `this.scene.children[1].prototype` is undefined :/

Comment: I was just editing my answer to show "constructor" instead, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: Thanks Sk93! I always find the answer when Ive already posted :´)

Comment: please tick your answer (or mine :P) as the accepted answer if this is now solved. the tick should appear below the up/down arrows and big number to the left of the answers. :)